# How to get indices as well as array numbers printed out horizontally?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an assignment of which a part is to generate n random numbers between 0-99 inclusive in a 1d array, where the user enters n. Now, I have to print out those numbers formatted like this:

```
What is your number? 22 //user entered

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
----random numbers here---------

11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
-----random numbers here--------

21 22
---two random numbers here---
```

Using those numbers, I have find lots of other things, (like min, max, median, outliers, etc.) and I was able to do so. However, I wasn't able to actually print it out in the format shown above, with no more than 10 numbers in one row.

Edit: Hello, I managed to figure it out, here's how I did it:

```java
        int counter = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        int count3 = 0;
        int add = 0;
        
        int idx = 1;
        int idx2 = 0;
        
        if (nums > 10)
        {
            count3 = 10;
            count2 = 10;
        }
        else 
        {
            count3 = nums;
            count2 = nums;
        }
        
        if (nums%10 == 0) add = 0;
        else add = 1;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < nums/10 + add; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < count3; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(idx + "\t");
                idx++;
            }
            
            System.out.println();
            
            for (int k = 0; k < count2; k++)
            {
                System.out.print(numbers[idx2] + "\t");
                idx2++;
                counter++;
            }
            
            System.out.println("\n");
            
            if (nums-counter > 10)
            {
                count3 = 10;
                count2 = 10;
            }
            else 
            {
                count3 = nums-counter;
                count2 = nums-counter;
            }
        }
```

Thank you to everyone who helped! Also, please let me know if you find a way to shorten what I have done above.

*above, `nums` was the number of numbers the user entered

Comment: Are you able to print the first 10 on the same line?

Comment: @PM77-1, yes, I was able to do so

Comment: What about the second group of 10?  Do you know about modulo `%` operation?

Comment: @PM77-1, yeah, I do know about the % operator, and I was also able to print out the next group of 10 (but not correctly). I will edit my original post to show you what I have done

Comment: Very good idea.

Comment: @PM77-1 just did so

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a for-loop to make an array of arrays: and then formatting the lines using those values:

```
var arr_random_n = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,6,4,6,7,4,7,3,1,5,7,9,5,3,2,54,6,8,5,2];
var organized_arr = [];
var idx = 0
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=10){
   organized_arr[idx] = arr.slice(i, i+10); //getting values in groups of 10
   idx+=1 //this variable represents the idx of the larger array
}
```

Now `organized_arr` has an array of arrays, where each array in index `i` contains the values to be printed in line `i`.

There's probably more concise ways of doing this. but this is very intuitive.
Let me know of any improvements.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't actually know a lot of the methods you used for the program, and I can't actually use those in my assignment. But thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be what you're looking for.

```
private static void printLine(String msg)
{
    System.out.println("\r\n== " + msg + " ==\r\n");
}

private static void printLine(int numDisplayed)
{
    printLine(numDisplayed + " above");
}

public static void test(int total)
{
    int[] arr = new int[total];

    // Fill our array with random values
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        arr[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);

    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");

        // Check if 10th value on the line, if so, display line break
        // ** UNLESS it's also the last value - in that case, don't bother, special handling for that
        if (i % 10 == 9 && i != total - 1)
            printLine("Random Numbers");
    }

    // Display number of displayed elements above the last line
    if (total < 10 || total % 10 != 0)
        printLine(total % 10);
    else
        printLine(10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To print 10 indexes on a line then those elements of an array, use two String variables to build the lines, then print them in two nested loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i += 10) {
    String indexes = "", elements = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < 10 &&  i * 10 + j < array.length; j++) {
        int index = i * 10 + j;
        indexes += (index + 1) + " "; // one-based as per example in question
        elements += array[index] + " ";
    }
    System.out.println(indexes);
    System.out.println(elements);
}
```